# grails plugin reloading

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

When developing a Grails plugin, you can configure it to reload using either the `watchedResources` or `observe` properties. From my reading of the official docs, it seems that the former will cause the plugin to reload when a file changes, and the latter when a plugin changes, is that correct?

Say for example, a plugin needs to reload itself any time a Grails service changes, are the following equivalent?

```
def watchedResources = "file:./grails-app/services/*Service.groovy"
def observe = ["services"]
```

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 4):

These are both described here: http://www.grails.org/Auto+Reloading+Plugins

Your plugin won't be reloaded, rather an event will be fired that you can handle in your onChange() callback. One use case is annotated artifacts; if you monitor changes in those and one gets changed, you can re-run whatever configuration changes you made based on the new values.

Comment: Link broken. I think this is a more up to date link http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.4/guide/plugins.html#participatingInAutoReloadEvents (I am interested in getting this functionality working too!)